# Compile QEMU under Windows 10 (64-bit) for Windows 10 (64-bit)

Tags: qemu

I managed to compile QEMU (3.0.50) under Windows 10 (64-bit) (basically following [these instructions](https://wiki.qemu.org/Hosts/W32#Native_builds_with_MSYS2)) with these commands:

```
./configure --enable-gtk --enable-sdl
make
```

However, when starting `qemu-system-x86_64.exe` in a console, nothing happens. I expected a window showing up. Shortly after starting the exe, I'm getting back the prompt. Nothing printed out to the console. No necessary DLL is missing. What could be the problem?

Comment: Anything in the event log?

Comment: Ah. Thanks. Good idea. Yes. There's an event:

Faulting application name: qemu-system-x86_64.exe, Version: 3.0.50.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Faulting module name: qemu-system-x86_64.exe, Version: 3.0.50.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000003da784

Comment: How do I find best the reason for the crash? Rebuild QEMU with ./configure --enable-debug added and then debugging it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally I managed to compile and run QEMU under Windows 10 Home 64-bit.
There are a few pitfalls:

1. Due to a compiler bug in mingw (see https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86832 and https://www.mail-archive.com/qemu-devel@nongnu.org/msg557409.html), you have to configure QEMU with --disable-stack-protector and (one solution) add the function __stack_chk_fail to a source file.
2. Configure QEMU with --disable-werror.
3. Remove Capstone project from makefile.

---

Here's a complete step-by-step guide for compiling qemu-system-x86_64.exe:

Date: 2018-10-31

OS: Microsoft Windows 10 Home 64-bit

Guide based on: https://wiki.qemu.org/Hosts/W32#Native_builds_with_MSYS2

- Download and install msys2 to C:\msys64:
  http://repo.msys2.org/distrib/x86_64/msys2-x86_64-20180531.exe
- Start C:\msys64\mingw64.exe
- Updates (then close window and restart mingw64.exe): pacman -Syu
- Updates: pacman -Su
- Install basic packets: pacman -S base-devel mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain git python
- Install QEMU specific packets: pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-glib2 mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3 mingw-w64-x86_64-SDL2
- Get QEMU sources:

  - git clone git://git.qemu-project.org/qemu.git
  - cd qemu
  - git submodule update --init ui/keycodemapdb
  - git submodule update --init capstone
  - git submodule update --init dtc
- Insert
  void __stack_chk_fail(void);
  void __stack_chk_fail(void)
  {
  }
  to qemu\util\oslib-win32.c
  e.g. at line 44
- Comment out (#) Capstone (line 508) in qemu\Makefile
- Build QEMU:

  - ./configure --enable-gtk --enable-sdl --target-list=x86_64-softmmu --disable-werror --disable-stack-protector
  - make
- Run in qemu/x86_64-softmmu
  ./qemu-system-x86_64 -L ./../pc-bios
- Optional (for better performance): Install HAXM according to this guide: https://www.qemu.org/2017/11/22/haxm-usage-windows/ and start QEMU with option -accel hax

Comment: Instead of commenting out capstone line, you can add --disable-capstone to configure arguments. Commenting out did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I would do know if somebody tried in 2022 i have currently some issues after compiling.
Firt it asks for libzstd.dll, when i go to the project i found by google and dl this dll, i encounter another issue

with x64.dll

[image]

with x32.dll (just in case)

[image]

i use msys2 minGw x64 on windows 10 pro x64. At the beginning i would compile a patch, but it the same problem with vanilla, i ask myself if it's an environment problem, a missing dll, or if it's always possible to compile directly on windows10, perhaps now it's only possible to compile in cross platform. I'm not habit at all with mingw64 tools.

I looked for the g_spanw... error and found this https://docs.gtk.org/glib/func.spawn_async_with_fds.html

Perhaps i'm wrong but it's only for gnome, isn't it ?