# XV6 make file issues "unrecognised emulation mode: -N" when trying to make xv6 on Windows

Tags: makefile, qemu, xv6

```
$ make qemu-nox
ld -m  -N -e main -Ttext 0 -o _cat cat.o ulib.o usys.o printf.o umalloc.o
C:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe: unrecognised emulation mode: -N
Supported emulations: i386pe
make: *** [_cat] Error 1
```

I keep getting this error although I have installed QEMU and followed this guide step by step: [Other SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53084815/compile-qemu-under-windows-10-64-bit-for-windows-10-64-bit).

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a line does behave as wanted:

```
 LDFLAGS += -m $(shell $(LD) -V | grep elf_i386 2>/dev/null | head -n 1)
```

As you can see, this line build the command line for `ld` and try to enable emulation mode (`-m`) for `elf`.

It seems that your `ld` does not support this kind of executable.

So, what can you do?

- You can try to remove the `LDFLAGS` to use the default emulation mode (i386pe) but I don't think it will work
- You can install a version of `ld` that support `elf` binary. Once you've installed it, you will certainly have an executable named like `i386-elf-ld`, if so, launch your build with `TOOLPREFIX=i386-elf- make qemu-nox`